# ¿Cómo hago para fijar 2 columnas a la vez en una VDataTable?

Tags: javascript, datatables, vue3, vuetify

Tengo una tabla donde quiero fijar las 2 columnas que son codigo_material y descripción, estaba usando fixed, que me fija correctamente pero solo 1 a la vez, ya que cuando scroleo, se pierde el primero y queda fijado solo el segundo, y lo que busco es que ambas queden fijas al moverse la tabla, **¿Cómo para que ambas queden fijadas a la vez?**. *Estoy trabajando con vuetify y vue 3*.

```
<template>

        <VDataTable
                        :headers="headers"
                        :items="dataApi"
                        item-key="name"
                        class="elevation-0"
                        fixed-header
                    >
                        <template v-slot:no-data>
                            <VAlert :value="true" color="warning" icon="tabler-alert-triangle">
                                Lo sentimos, no hay datos aquí
                            </VAlert>
                        </template>
                    </VDataTable>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name: "Consolidado",
    data(){
        return{
            headers: [
                    { title: 'ID', key: 'id_version'},
                    { title: 'Código Material', key: 'codigo_material', fixed: true},
                    { title: 'Descripción', key: 'descripcion', fixed: true},
                    { title: 'Mes 1', key: 'mes_01_stock_costo_existencias_tn', align: 'center'},
                    { title: 'Mes 1', key: 'mes_01_stock_costo_existencias_costo_x_tn', align: 'center'},
                    { title: 'Mes 1', key: 'mes_01_proyeccion_ventas'},
                    { title: 'Mes 2', key: 'mes_02_proyeccion_ventas'},
                    { title: 'Mes 3', key: 'mes_03_proyeccion_ventas'},
            ],
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Se soluciono poniendo,

```
width: 200
```

en cada columna, donde quería fijar.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.